# Do I need to do a full body routine before I follow beginners' routines

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, beginners

I hit the gym yesterday after I found a "3 day split" routine which I feel like it sounds good, but I want to ask whether should I do like, what I know as general/full body training for certain period of time-could be two weeks to a month-before I set my self to follow that routine..
or Just follow the routine and I would be fine

here is the routine workout to check it 
http://www.jcdfitness.com/jcdfitness-beginners-muscle-building-routine/

and also this one, but now I follow the former:

http://www.aworkoutroutine.com/the-beginner-weight-training-workout-routine/

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I don't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have found a routine that meets your goals - be those strength, aesthetics, endurance or just one that interests you - there is nothing that says you can't go straight into that program, *if you do it safely*.

Start at a low weight, focus on form, and gradually increase the weight in accordance with your routines programming.

There is no reason not to start a program if you can do it constantly, in a controlled manner for a enough time to see the required changes.

While some programs may be more optimal for some goals, if you are unable or unwilling to do them as prescribed for whatever reason, they will be less suitbale than a program you can follow.

Comment: Well,FYI I'm a newbie and the program says it works for beginners of all goals, but coz last time I read @ one site a guy recommending a comprehensive one month training for beginners-as it claims- so I thought I should do so, and that's the reason of my question...regrading that specific program which I follow now,I just like how the guy explains things and makes it clear. but you know newbie can't really decide if that program is really what works for me or not..maybe if you could have a look and give your comments,that would be much appreciated dude :)